# Mysql retrieve last 30 days data and sum it by days

Tags: mysql

I want to group all last 30 days purchases in a store by each day and return last 30 days array of following data for example

```
2017/04/01
purchases: 30
total: 900.01

2017/04/02
purchases: 30
total: 900.01
```

and so on. so far I have no idea how to make this kind of query and came up with following idea

```
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(purchases.price)/1000,0) AS all_purchases, 
    min(purchases.time) AS start_interval, max(purchases.time) AS end_interval
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchases.time::date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND WHERE purchases.time::date <= DATE_SUB(NOW())
    ORDER BY start_interval DESC
```

but thats not how it works

Comment: you question says, "Group all last 30 days purchase ***in a store*** by each day"... where is store in your query/structure or is it incorrect in the question?  or is store in reference to retail sale in store vs online and how would we know the differences?

Answer (score 4):

You should use group by  eg:

```
  SELECT date(purchases.time) as my_date ,  count(*) as my_count, 
          COALESCE(SUM(purchases.price)/1000,0) AS all_purchases
  FROM purchases
  WHERE date(purchases.time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
         AND   date(purchases.time) <= CURDATE()
  GROUP BY date(purchases.time)
  ORDER BY my_date DESC
```

(and you should use where only one time  .. not where  ..and where but  where ... and  .. )

Comment: are you sure its syntax is good? because I'm getting syntax error message. And also I'm pretty sure its not the answer I need since I'm searching query which would display all purchases by each day